# Fetch custom dropdown in Magento frontend

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have already added custom table called quantities in database. I want to show this as drop down in front end.

```
       $model = Mage::getModel('quantities/quantities')->load($_product->getId());
```

How to fetch this data and show as dropdown. I am new to Magento.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('quantities/quantities')->load($_product->getId());

<select>

<?php foreach($model->getData() as $_data): ?>

<option><?php echo $_data->getYourAttribute() ?></option>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</select>
```

Granted you know what data is contained in your model. If not just var_dump($_data) or you can print_r($_data)

Answer (score 1):

In the template (*.phtml) file, using Magento Block like this...

```
<?php
    $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
    ->setName('data['.$selectName.']')
    ->setId("sel_$selectId")
    ->setClass('quantity-select')
    ->setOptions($model->getData())
    ->setValue($value);
    echo $select->getHtml();
?>
```

or Building it from scratch...

```
<select name="sel_name" id="sel_id">
    <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
    <?php foreach ($model->getData() as $key => $value): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Will this do?